# It was explained or it has been explained?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

I don't known which of the following I should use, because it translates with the same words.

> It was explained to him that nothing else could be done!

> It has been explained to him that nothing else could be done!

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect 'has been' has a present significance, the use would be related to the present situation or discussion in some way, affecting it.
The simple past would suggest there's not necessarily a connection to the present in any way- the time and the situation are over.

Comment: For example,  the second is in a higher register and sounds more like something you'd use as a justification for not talking to someone who wants to revisit some matter. It has been explained before so we aren't going to go through it again.

Comment: I love all of you!!